# Projection on the coordinate plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$ with usual inner product.
>   Find the orthogonal projection matrix on coordinate plane $xy$ and
>   $xz$

I think that projection on xy is $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and on xz is $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Anyone can help me?

Comment: These are correct.  Note that $A[x, y, z]^{T}=[x, y, 0]^{T}$ in the first case and $[x, 0, z]^{T}$ in the second.

Comment: Sure.  To test, just apply your matrices to a general vector $(x,y,z)$ to verify your statement.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Only need to do this to verify that the projection in xy and yz?

Comment: @askazy  Yes.  Your first matrix $A$ takes an arbitrary vector $(x,y,z)$ and produces a vector $(x,y,0)$.  That's what we mean by lying on the $x-y$ plane, i.e., a projection onto that plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear map is known by its values on a basis. Compute the map in a basis, and put the coordinates into columns. With suggestive notation: $$\begin{cases} \pi_{xy}(1,0,0) = (1,0,0) \\ \pi_{xy}(0,1,0) = (0,1,0) \\ \pi_{xy}(0,0,1) = (0,0,0) \end{cases} \implies \pi_{xy} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and similarly for the other one.

Comment: Not need to use anything on orthogonal projection matrix?

Comment: I didn't follow. What you didn't understand?

Comment: I understand it's thought that it might be more complicated.

Comment: You only have to look at the projections of a basis. One nice exercise to make sure the point hits home is writing the projection on the plane $y=z$, say.